# What happened to the question about polynomials with integer coefficients and $p(x) < 1/(1+x)$?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I saw a question yesterday, asking for polynomials with integer coefficients satisfying $p(x) \geq 0$ on $[-2,2]$ and $p(x) < 1/(1+x)$ on $(-1,2)$. What happened to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1285979). At least I assume that's the one you were talking about. It had been deleted by the owner, and I took the step to undelete it.